# For the following code snippet, I need help for writing JUnit test case. Any solution or code hint would be appreciated

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

For the following code, am not sure of how to test list and array list.
Any solution would be very helpful.
And also the asserts that must be used here.

```
public List<Handler> getHandlerChain(PortInfo portInfo) {
    log.debug(">> getHandlerChain() Begin");

    if (handlerList == null) {
        handlerList = new ArrayList<Handler>();

        handlerList.add(JaxWsSecurityHandler);  
    }

    log.debug("<< getHandlerChain() End");
    return handlerList;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering, getHandlerChain method is inside class Chain. Then testcase will be something like this.

```
public class ChainTest {

Chain chain;

@Before
public void setup() {
    chain = new Chain();
}

@Test
public void shouldReturnListOfHandlers() {

    PortInfo portInfo = Mockito.mock(PortInfo.class);
    List<Handler> handlers = chain.getHandlerChain(portInfo);
    Assert.assertNotNull(handlers);
    Assert.assertEquals(1, handlers.size());
    Assert.assertTrue(handlers.get(0) instanceOf Object);   //This should be exact assertion of whats present in index 0
}
```

}